# Is there a way to persist data under multiple keys using redux-persist?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage, redux-persist

I work on a big application where we store some data locally using react-persist using AsyncStorage. Since all the data is stored under a single key in react-persist, this fills up the read buffer limitation of 2MB for SQLite on Android. I was wondering if there's a way to store that data under multiple keys and not run into the problem that we are right now.